# Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers Without HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine

We have a website hosted with WordPress in Google App engine flexi environment which does not use .HTACCESS. The URL of the site is https://www.answerforce.com/

Now, we need to fix this -  Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers warning in Google page speed insights. How can I achieve it? I know this is usually achieved with a code in the .HTACCESS file but since the environment (Google App engine Flexi) does not make use of the .HTACCESS file, I cannot use the htaccess code. I have tried different wordpress caching plugins but none of them have worked.

Link to more information on App engine flexible environment -- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

Answer (score 1):

Appears you are using WordPress.  There is a plug in to do this:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/http-headers/